# GCC - Print the definition of a struct

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Is it possible for a **C** program to print the definition of a struct? Member names would be great to have, but just an ordered list of data types (and array length in case of arrays) would be sufficient.

I was looking for preprocessor directives to achieve this, but could not find any. Is there a preprocessor directive that can grab an annotated part of code and use it as a #define variable. If so I could initialize some sting variables with to hold the value of the #define variables.

For example a structure like this get printed as-is

```
struct foo{
int a;
char b;
short arr[6];
}
```

or like this

```
struct s{
int m1;
char m2;
short m3[6];
}
```

The formatting is not important as long as the structure can be recreated from the data. So something like this is also fine:

```
s{int,char,short[10]}
```

Just FYI this is a resource constrained ARM based device.

I don't want to manually copy paste the struct code into a print statement. If the struct code changes, and the print statement is not changed, it would yield wrong results.

Comment: Not in standard C, as far as I know. And definitely not through the C preprocessor (by "a #define variable", you mean a C preprocessor macro), since it doesn't have any idea how C itself works.

Comment: @Rhymoid wouldn't agree on that; you could use the preprocessor to make a copy of the code in question for a `#define structname_code ...` and also instantiate it.

Comment: "I don't want to manually copy paste the struct code" - you can make the program read its own source code file.

Comment: It second @MarcusMüller. You can create defines which encapsulate type and member definitions and put the names in data structures which you evaluate later.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller this should be an answer

Comment: @RadLexus Yes, as a last resort but if the existing mechanisms can be harnessed, nothing like it.

Answer (score 1):

There are object file formats which contain the information you need, and allow for programmatic access. One of them is [Dwarf](http://dwarfstd.org/). Debuggers typically use this information.

I don't think (but I'm not sure) that it is possible to access the debug information for the *running code*. This is  a difference to programs in languages which run in an elaborate run time system like Java or the .net family. Those can use reflection on themselves.

In programs written in traditionally compiled languages you probably would open an object file -- possibly the running executable itself! -- and examine it programmatically, much like a debugger does. Considering that, it is conceivable that it would be easier to analyze the source code (which in C and C++ must be available for many type definitions in the form of header files). But for non-trivial uses that idea may be deceiving because the compiler has lexed and parsed the source for you and put all the information in neat data structures where they can be easily accessed. This part of the compilation process -- i.e. a considerable part of the front end -- would have to be done by you if you operate on the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that if you already have the source code?

But in general, C compilers don't offer an option to e.g. "list" all the structures it has seen during compilation. The compiler will keep internal symbol tables, but no-one has thought of any need to be able to print these. There also may be hundreds of structs and types in all the source and header files read during the compilation.

Note also that names of types, fields and variables are primarily there to give meaning to the programmer. After compilation, many names will be gone. Only global variables and missing external variables will retain their name in the object file to be able to resolve these during linking, and after linking, neither these names are needed anymore. The compiler has for example translated `a->b` into the offset of `b` relatieve to the place in memory where `a` resides.

Comment: "Why would you want to do that if you already have the source code?" I have embedded IoT device. There could be many such devices on field. The device is going to send binary blobs. These devices could be running different firmware versions and blob structure could vary depending of firmware version. The conventional approach is to convey the firmware version and make the sever aware of blob structures for each version. To complicate matters further the device memory can contain data stored by previous firmware versions.  I would like to make the data self descriptive.

Comment: There are workarounds that do not involve knowing the structure. But they are messy and impose constraints. I like the idea of JSON / bJSON. It the only downside with this is the data overhead, once you have paid that price, it makes for a very agile information system where all nodes don't have to be on the same version to communicate successfully.

Comment: And the reason I wouldn't paste the struct in a sprintf is mentioned in the question itself. Maybe as a last resort I'd do that but I'm trying find better ways to do it. One user has actually left a pretty usable hack in the comment.

Comment: -1, because GCC has -save-temps, which creates a .self-contained file including "all the structures it has seen during compilation", among other things.